# Errors when saving a Keras ML model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am getting an error saving a ML model. I searched here on SO and it looked like the advice was to change the parameters of the function to be `'=None'`. But when I tried that, I got an error that `None types are not iterable`. Any ideas?

```
# Save the model
model.save('./alexnet_model.hdf5')
# Load the model
alexnet_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('./alexnet_model.hdf5', custom_objects={'AlexNet': AlexNet})
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-76-504e90d49459> in <module>()
      6 model.save('./alexnet_model.hdf5')
      7 # Load the model
----> 8 alexnet_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('./alexnet_model.hdf5', custom_objects={'AlexNet': AlexNet})
      9 #alexnet_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('./alexnet_model.hdf5')

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/sequential.py in from_config(cls, config, custom_objects)
    428       build_input_shape = None
    429       layer_configs = config
--> 430     model = cls(name=name)
    431     for layer_config in layer_configs:
    432       layer = layer_module.deserialize(layer_config,

TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'input_shape' and 'num_classes'
```

Here is the first few lines of the model architecture:

```
# Define the AlexNet model
class AlexNet(Sequential):
   def __init__(self, input_shape, num_classes, **kwargs):
    super().__init__()
```

Tried to update AlexNet architecture with the get_config function:

```
# Define the AlexNet model
class AlexNet(Sequential):
   def __init__(self, input_shape, num_classes, **kwargs):
    super().__init__()

    self.add(Conv2D(96, kernel_size=(11,11), strides= 4,
                    padding= 'valid', activation= 'relu',
                    input_shape= input_shape, kernel_initializer= 'he_normal'))
    self.add(BatchNormalization())
    self.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3,3), strides= (2,2),
                          padding= 'valid', data_format= None))
    
    
    self.add(Conv2D(256, kernel_size=(5,5), strides= 1,
                    padding= 'same', activation= 'relu',
                    kernel_initializer= 'he_normal'))
    self.add(BatchNormalization())
    self.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3,3), strides= (2,2),
                          padding= 'valid', data_format= None)) 
    

    self.add(Conv2D(384, kernel_size=(3,3), strides= 1,
                    padding= 'same', activation= 'relu',
                    kernel_initializer= 'he_normal'))
    self.add(BatchNormalization())
    
    self.add(Conv2D(384, kernel_size=(3,3), strides= 1,
                    padding= 'same', activation= 'relu',
                    kernel_initializer= 'he_normal'))
    self.add(BatchNormalization())
    
    self.add(Conv2D(256, kernel_size=(3,3), strides= 1,
                    padding= 'same', activation= 'relu',
                    kernel_initializer= 'he_normal'))
    self.add(BatchNormalization())
    
    self.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3,3), strides= (2,2),
                          padding= 'valid', data_format= None))
    

    self.add(Flatten())
    
    self.add(Dense(num_classes, activation= 'sigmoid')) #try sigmoid vs. softmax

    self.compile(optimizer= tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=lr_schedule),
                loss='binary_crossentropy',
                metrics=['accuracy'])

   def get_config(self):
     return {'input_shape': (256, 256, 3), 'num_classes': 3}
```

Still getting the same error:

```
# Save the model
model.save('./alexnet_model.hdf5')
# Load the model
alexnet_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('./alexnet_model.hdf5', custom_objects={'AlexNet': AlexNet})
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you define `get_config` method in your model to return your init params?
Can you look at their tutorial again to compare your model configuration?

https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize

Answer (score 2):

As [@firattamur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16634193/firattamur) mentioned, you need to add a `get_config` method which can return the parameters of the constructor while deserializing the model. See [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize#custom_objects) section in [Save and Load Keras models](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize#custom_objects). It mentions that,

> The architecture of subclassed models and layers are defined in the
> methods `__init__` and `call`. They are considered Python bytecode, which
> cannot be serialized into a JSON-compatible config -- you could try
> serializing the bytecode (e.g. via `pickle`), but it's completely unsafe
> and means your model cannot be loaded on a different system.
>
> In order to save/load a model with custom-defined layers, or a
> subclassed model, you should overwrite the `get_config` and optionally
> `from_config` methods. Additionally, you should use register the custom
> object so that Keras is aware of it.

Add the `get_config` method to your class `AlexNet`,

```
class AlexNet(Sequential):

   def __init__(self, input_shape, num_classes, **kwargs):
    super().__init__()

   def call( self , inputs ):
    ...

   def get_config( self ):
      # Modify these according to your requirements
      return { 'input_shape' : ( 224 , 224 , 1 ) , 
               'num_classes' : 3 }
```

Comment: Just to confirm- get_config should not be inside the __itit__ function? I'm still getting the same error with this line of code: alexnet_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('./alexnet_model.hdf5', custom_objects={'AlexNet': AlexNet}). Do I need to change anything there?

Comment: I added an update with the full model architecture